# Configure Kotlin for Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-electric-eel

When I updated to Electric Eel 2022.1.1, every time I create a new Kotlin file, it gives me the notification warning `Configure Kotlin Configure 'Name.app' module in 'Name' project as`**`Kotlin (Android with Gradle) module`**.

I have only been working with Kotlin, not Java. I only started getting this warning after the update.

After I click the link to configure **as Kotlin (Android with Gradle) module** and select **All modules containing Kotlin files: Name.app** and set the Kotlin compiler to **1.8.0**, it still gives me another warning when I make a new file.

Do I need to worry about this warning or can I just ignore it?

Here is my build.gradle (:app)

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
android {
    namespace 'com.example.name'
    compileSdk 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.name"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

and here is the top-level `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something you should worry about. I would recommend sticking to Kotlin 1.8.0 for the time being as an upgrade may cause some compatibility issues with some other dependencies. Mainly material. Also, core-ktx is specified 3 times in your dependencies so I think that's something you need to look into

Comment: AS usually tells me to stick to Kotlin 1.7.20 because of compatibility issues as you mentioned, anything above usually gives me errors

Comment: 1.8.0 is working just fine. I've been using it for a while now and haven't had any issues with it. the only issues I got was when I used Kotlin 1.8.20-Beta in a compose project and it wasn't compatible with material3. I solved that by looking at [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin)